# The Relationship Between Voltage and the Strength of an Electromagnetic Force

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm having a bit of trouble with a science lab for school.
We were given this information:
The strength of the electromagnetic field (B)  is given by

[image]

μ and  are constant values that don’t change.
I = Current
r= distance from the electromagnet

The questions I have are:

What is μ? It seems to have differing values across multiple areas.

What does the small 0 in the subscript below μ mean?

There is a section in which I am asked what the gradient of the graph means, and I am stumped.

Since x (the current) is also divided by 2pi*r, is there any way I could possibly split the equation up to see what the gradient is equal to?

If somebody could help, that would be amazing!

Comment: Welcome to the site! For questions like this that are directly related to an assignment, it's best to show us what you've tried to do. Like what is the graph you are referring to (sounds like a result of a measurement of some kind), and what values of $\mu$ are you finding?

Comment: For your graph, for which you need the gradient, what are you graphing on the $x$ and $y$ axes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mu_0$ is called the magnetic constant. Like how you see $\pi$ in all circle equations, get used to seeing $\mu_0$ in magnetic field equations!

$\mu$ is the magnetic permeability of a medium. It represents how easily a magnetic field can be formed in that medium. $\mu_0$ is just the $\mu$ of free space. It's a fundamental constant of our universe. The subscript zero ultimately means nothing more than 'of free space'.

I won't give you the answer to your problem, but I'll give you a hint. Pull out the constants.

$$B=\frac{\mu_0}{2\pi}\cdot\frac{I}{r}$$